# Analysis of recursive approach for rotating an array of integers

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, time-complexity

While solving Array rotation on LeetCode, I wrote a recursive algorithm to solve the problem:

> Given an array, rotate the array to the right by k steps, where k is
> non-negative.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input: nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], k = 3 Output: [5,6,7,1,2,3,4]
> Explanation: rotate 1 steps to the right: [7,1,2,3,4,5,6] rotate 2
> steps to the right: [6,7,1,2,3,4,5] rotate 3 steps to the right:
> [5,6,7,1,2,3,4]
>
> Example 2:
>
> Input: nums = [-1,-100,3,99], k = 2 Output: [3,99,-1,-100]
> Explanation:  rotate 1 steps to the right: [99,-1,-100,3] rotate 2
> steps to the right: [3,99,-1,-100]
>
> Constraints:
>
> 1 <= nums.length <= 2*104
> -231 <= nums[i] <= 231 - 1
> 0 <= k <= 105

For further clarification the link to the problem is [here.](https://leetcode.com/problems/rotate-array/)

The solution I came up with is as follows:

```java
class Solution {
  public void rotate(int[] nums, int k) {
    rotateArr(nums, nums.length, k % nums.length, 0);
  }

  public static void rotateArr(int[] arr, int len, int steps, int current) {
    if (len <= steps) {
      return;
    }
    rotateArr(arr, len - 1, steps, current + 1);
    int stepsTaken = 0;
    int i = current;
    int temp;
    while (stepsTaken < steps) {
      temp = arr[i];
      arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
      arr[i + 1] = temp;
      i++;
      stepsTaken++;
    }
  }
}
```

According to my analysis of the solution the function ***rotateArr()*** will first divide, by recuring ***nums.length - k*** times. After that it start conquering, which will happen in ***nums.length - k + 1*** steps and at each step its performing ***k*** operations. Summing up everything we get:

- **(nums.length - k) + (nums.length - k + 1) k = nums.length  + nums.length k - k^2**

Although I have a quadratic term but its a constant, thus I believe my runtime is O(n).
I want to know the following:

- Is my analysis correct ?
- If it's correct, then why my runtime always falls arround 100 ms on LeetCode ? As opposed to others with 0 ms. Is it because of recursion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utkarsh Tiwari, I think your analysis is not correct. According to my calculation the conquer step will happen for `A.length - k` times and ***not*** `A.length - k + 1`.

Let us consider the second input array you mentioned:

```
[-1, -100, 3, 99]
```

Here the first call to *`rotateArray(A, 4, 2, 0)`* takes place in the `main()` method. The second recursive call is this: *`rotateArray(A, 3, 2, 1)`* and the last one is this: *`rotateArray(A, 2, 2, 2)`*.

*However, in the last recursive call the conquer will not take place since the base condition is satisfied.*

```
if(length <= steps) return.
```

*The function will simply return the last time without performing any significant steps.*
Hence, all the `k` number of operations will occur only in the first two recursive calls which is according to the expression `A.length - k` or `4-2` in this case.

Hence, the `time complexity` will be `(A.length-k) * k`.

Now, *lets look at the constraints you provided:*

> `1 <= nums.length <= 2 * 10^4`
>
> `-2^31 <= nums[i] <= 2^31 - 1`
>
> `0 <= k <= 10^5`

Here, `k` is **not** constant. Its possible value even exceeds the maximum value of `nums.length`. The `time complexity` depends ***both*** on the value of `A.length` and `k`. *It would have been `O(nums.length)` if the possible value of `k` were between 5 to 20. However, with current constraints it can take a value which is more than `A.length`.*

Lets notice another subtle detail in your implementation. In the first call to `rotateArray()`, you pass `k % A.length` as one of the parameters. Now the possible value of `k` reduces to:

```
0 <= k < A.length
```

*If we choose value of k as A.length/2 and put in our time complexity, we get:*

```
(A.length - A.length/2) * A.length
```

which reduces to `O(A.length^2)` which will be the `worst case complexity`.

I hope I have helped you. *Do comment if you face any problems in the solution.*